# select all nodes if another element has a certain value

Tags: xslt, xpath

If I have the xml document

```
<A>
  <B>TEXT</B>
  <C>
     <D>1</D>
     <E>2</E>
  </C>
  <C>
     <D>3</D>
     <E>4</E>
  </C>
</A>
```

Is it possible in a single xpath to get all values of A/C/D if the value of `<B>` is TEXT and select nothing if it is any other value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The path `/A[B = 'TEXT']/C/D` selects the two `D` elements in your sample.